# Angular2 Webpack2 file imports fail with error 404

Tags: angular, webpack-2

I am trying to build Angular2 project for production profile. 'dist' folder is created successfully, but the index.html does not load. It gives error 404 for imports:

- app.[hash].css
- polyfills.[hash].js
- vendor.[hash].js
- app.[hash].js

Whereas, the dev profile is working perfectly.

Code is available here - https://github.com/darshil-doshi/angular2-webpack2

For reference, I followed angular2-webpack tutorial (as it is) on https://angular.io/guide/webpack
I am using all the latest versions of webpack, loaders and plugins.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Use angular cli...

Comment: How do you load index.html?

Comment: You don't have an **entry section** in your webpack.config. Better use angular cli it's easier.

Comment: You're missing a css loader to read that css.

Comment: entry section and css loader along with other loaders are defined in webpack.common.js
dev profile works fine, hence I am sure this is not the cause